# Python code not working as expected

Tags: python

I am new to Python language, and I am running into this problem, the code below is not returning the expecting value:

```
def rabbits(n):
    first = 1
    second = 1

    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1
    while n > 2:
        first, second = second, first + second
        n -= 1

    if n > 5:
        die1 = 1
        die2 = 1
        if n == 6 or n == 7:
            return second - 1
        while n > 7:
            die1, die2 = die2, die1 + die2
            n -= 1
        return second - die2
    return second
```

I am hoping that rabbits(6) would be returning 7, but it returns 8 instead. Can anyone help me find the wrong stuff in here? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first reduce `n` to 2 or lower (`while n > 2: .. n -= 1`), then test if `n > 5`.

That latter test is never going to pass because `n` will now always be 2 or lower.

That first reduction calculates the fibonacci sequence, and the 6th value in that sequence is 8 (after 1, 1, 2, 3 & 5).

To avoid your problem, use a simple range loop instead:

```
for i in range(n, 2, -1):
    first, second = second, first + second
```

Now `i` will go from 6 to 3 without changing `n`.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it's useful to solve your problem as stated.

But here is some advice about debugging this type of problem, which is far more useful:

**print out your values at every stage of the program**

You can then step through the program in your mind, with your values, and find out what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, it should never return 7. You are calculating the fibonacci sequence. Its first few terms are 1,1,2,3,5,8,13. There is no 7.

The fibonacci sequence starts with 1,1 and then each next term is calculated as the sum of the two preceding ones. That is exactly what you are doing with the `first, second = second, first + second` statement. Therefore `rabbits(n) <=> fibonacci(n)`.

You might be expecting a 7 because of code inside the `if n > 5` branch. However, that branch never gets executed because n will always be less than or equal to two due to the `while n > 2` loop that precedes it.

Answer (score 0):

You're changing n in your `while n > 2` statement, use a copy of variable, or implement it in a better way.

```
def rabbits(n):
    first = 1
    second = 1

    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1
    m = n
    while m > 2:
        first, second = second, first + second
        m -= 1

    if n > 5:
        die1 = 1
        die2 = 1
        if n == 6 or n == 7:
            return second - 1
        while n > 7:
            die1, die2 = die2, die1 + die2
            n -= 1
        return second - die2
    return second
```